# How to get a Test Configuration's static Parameter's Default Value using ALM OTA from Test Plan?

Tags: hp-uft, alm, hp-alm, microfocus

I have to automate certain test cases, which inturn have more than 100 test configurations. These are not manual test types, but rather Business Components each configuration having it's own configuration Test data (static type) in Test Plan. So far, I am able to get each configuration's Test Parameters Name but not their Default value as available in Test Plan > Test > Configuration Tab > Data sub tab

```
<TestObject>.TestConfigFactory.Newlist("")(1).ParameterValueFactory.Newlist("").Item(1).Name
```

This gives the name of the configuration parameter name. The method "DefaultValue" is null for each test data, even though on visual inspection it does contain the value.

I am using VBScript.

Comment: Will having access to ALM Database Reference may help ?

Comment: The ParameterValue Object does hold an field "Default Value":
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/ota/Default.htm#ota/topic8123.html